# Ways to Increase Chromatic Number of Graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings

I'm wondering if there are known ways to *increase* the chromatic number of a graph, arising from a construction as follows.  Suppose $G$ is a finite graph with no loops or multiple edges, and let $G_i = G$ be $n$ copies of $G$.  Let $G_n = \uplus G_i$ be the disjoint union of the $G_i$'s, and let $\tilde{G}$ be any graph obtained from $G_n$ by adding edges $e = [v_i, v_j]$ where $v_i \in G_i$, $v_j \in G_j$ and $i \neq j$.

In other words, we take $n$ copies of $G$ like sheets and then add edges between the sheets.

For my problem, I want to start with such a graph $G$ and create a $\tilde{G_n}$ with $\chi(\tilde{G_n}) \geq \chi(G) + 2$.  However, there are various constraints, like for example my $\tilde{G_n}$ can't contain a $K_5$, and my $G$ can't contain a $K_4$ or $K_{2,3}$.

Are there constructions or operations on graphs that seem well-suited to studying such a problem?  Does this remind anyone of something they've seen?

I suppose that an explicit question would be this.  Given a graph $G$ and a collection $\mathcal{H}$ of 'forbidden subgraphs' $H_k$:

1: When is there an $n$ and $\tilde{G}_n$ with $\chi(\tilde{G}_n) > \chi(G)$ such that $\tilde{G}_n$ doesn't contain any $H_i$ as a subgraph?  What if $\mathcal{H}$ and/or $G$ are finite?

2: When can $\chi(\tilde{G}_n)$ be arbitrarily large?  Especially, when can it increase $\chi(G)$ by at least two?  How is it bounded by the structure of $G$?

3: What's the minimal $n$ when possible?  When is $n = 2$ sufficient?

4: Given a family $\mathcal{H}$, what graphs can (can't) have their chromatic numbers raised with such a procedure?  For a specific $\mathcal{H}$ does the collection $\mathcal{G}$ of graphs which can (can't) have their chromatic numbers raised have any nice structure or ruled by any invariants?

5: Is it always possible for almost all graphs when $\mathcal{H}$ is finite?  With just $n = 2$?

There are various trivial examples in all directions, but any interesting ones?  In my case, there will also be a global restriction on how each sheet is connected to each other, which eliminates a lot of the trivialities resulting in the above:

1st Variant: Suppose in addition that the number of edges between two sheets $G_i, G_j$ is bounded as a function $f$ of $|v(G)|$.

2nd Variant: Suppose instead that there is a locality condition defined by some fixed $f$ on $\mathbb{N}$; if $v \in G_i$ is connected to $w, x \in G_j$ with $i \neq j$, then there is a path between $w, x$ in $G_j$ of length less than or equal to $f(n)$.

Mostly just curious if there any known constructions similar to this.

Comment: I posted a more general question over here and people offered some good ideas for my particular problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4001754/how-to-construct-graphs-with-high-chromatic-number-but-no-complete-subgraphs  Seems that "triangle-free graphs with high chromatic number" is a topic that has a good body of literature associated with it.